# how to insert random records without violating primary constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, duplicates, distinct

Please pardon my title if misleading, but I have a table `tb_party` with `PRIMARY KEY on party_key`

I have following query -

```
 insert TMS..tb_party
        (
            [party_key]
            ,[party_first_name]
            ,[tax_id]
            ,[party_type_cd]
            ,[citizenship_country_cd]
            ,[domicile_country_cd]
            ,[party_num]
            ,[batch_dt]
        )


    select distinct
            [party_key]
            ,[party_first_name]
            ,[tax_id]
            ,[party_type_cd]
            ,[cit]
            ,[dom]
            ,[party_num]
            ,[batch_dt]

        from 
        (select distinct
                 sca.[party_key]
                ,sca.[party_first_name]
                ,sca.[tax_id]
                ,pt.party_type_cd
                ,tc_cit.COUNTRY_ID as cit
                ,tc_dom.COUNTRY_ID as dom
                ,sca.[party_num]
                ,getdate() as batch_dt
                ,dense_rank() over(partition by sca.[party_key] order by sca.party_key) as rnk
            from Iteration_3.dbo.staging_cust_acct  sca     (nolock)
            join Iteration_3..STG_PARTY_UPLOAD (nolock) stg_party
                on sca.party_key = stg_party.PARTY_KEY
            left join Iteration_3..STG_COUNTRY_ISO              tc_dom  (nolock)
                on sca.[domicile_country] = tc_dom.COUNTRY_NAME
            left join Iteration_3..STG_COUNTRY_ISO              tc_cit  (nolock)
                on sca.[citizenship_country] = tc_cit.COUNTRY_NAME
            left join TMS..tb_party_type                pt      (nolock)
                on sca.[party_type] = pt.party_type_desc
            WHERE  
            SCA.party_type IS NOT NULL
            ) x 
        where rnk = 1
```

The insert fails because it is trying to insert duplicate party key and since the distinct is on ALL columns, it is picking up duplicate party_keys.

What I want - I want to pick up **all** distinct party_keys and insert 1 row in tb_party. the other rows can be ignored. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is where row_number came in handy.

```
select distinct
        [party_key]
        ,[party_first_name]
        ,[tax_id]
        ,[party_type_cd]
        ,[cit]
        ,[dom]
        ,[party_num]
        ,[batch_dt]

    from 
    (


        select distinct
             sca.[party_key]
            ,sca.[party_first_name]
            ,sca.[tax_id]
            ,pt.party_type_cd
            ,tc_cit.COUNTRY_ID as cit
            ,tc_dom.COUNTRY_ID as dom
            ,sca.[party_num]
            ,getdate() as batch_dt
            --,dense_rank() over(partition by sca.[party_key] order by sca.party_key,sca.[tax_id],sca.[party_num],sca.[party_first_name]*/) as rnk
            ,row_number() over (partition by sca.party_key order by sca.party_key) rn
        from Iteration_3.dbo.staging_cust_acct  sca     (nolock)
        join Iteration_3..STG_PARTY_UPLOAD (nolock) stg_party
            on sca.party_key = stg_party.PARTY_KEY
        left join Iteration_3..STG_COUNTRY_ISO              tc_dom  (nolock)
            on sca.[domicile_country] = tc_dom.COUNTRY_NAME
        left join Iteration_3..STG_COUNTRY_ISO              tc_cit  (nolock)
            on sca.[citizenship_country] = tc_cit.COUNTRY_NAME
        left join TMS..tb_party_type                pt      (nolock)
            on sca.[party_type] = pt.party_type_desc
        WHERE --SCA.update_source  = 'ECM' AND SCA.update_dt = @ECM_MAX_DATE
        --and 
        SCA.party_type IS NOT NULL
        ) x 
    where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try merging into your target table on the unique columns. When not matched, insert. When matched update like this:
...
set target.[column] = coalesce(source.[column], target.[column])
...
This way you update all your target columns when you have source values, otherwise they remain unchanged.)

Comment: Thanks @Katherine but I could get it easily inserted using ROW_NUMBER. I added the answer but thanks a ton.